# Best first night shelter design in minecraft for the ultimate survival noob

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been playing minecraft for a while, but I have never played survival. All I know is just a little bit about it. Anyways, while I was playing survival for the first time, I was constantly getting killed by enemies due to my lack of sufficent shelter. Is there a best method for building a first night shelter? (Btw, all the tutorials I looked up were too complicated for an ultimate survival noob like me.) Also, if you want to, could you throw in some easy to follow online tutorials?

Comment: This was probably downvoted because regardless of how 'noob' you claim to be, learning how to do this is so incredibly obvious and simple, especially with google and youtube available, that it shows a lack of research effort. A perfect example is the linked duplicate question, that already answers this question. If you had simply used our 'search' command you would have had your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest and most effective way to build a shelter for your first night, is to chop down about 20 blocks of wood.

Use your fists for the first few blocks, then turn the wood into planks, and some of the planks into a crafting table and some sticks. Use your new supplies to build your basic wooden tools to get you started.

Once you have your tools and roughly 10-20 additional wood blocks, simply dig into the dirt anywhere you want, a 2 block deep, six wide by six long hole should be more than sufficient.

Dig a staircase method 1 block wide tunnel into the dirt anywhere for some stone, use your wooden pickaxe to grab 8 stone blocks and take them back to you 'hole'. Use your crafting table to turn the stone into a furnace.

Use the furnace to turn your wood into charcoal. (if you have no other fuel, a block of wood as fuel works fine to get you started)

With the charcoal you can now make torches to light up the inside of your hole, place them, then put a roof over your hole using the dirt you dug up to make the hole in the first place.

Comment: You could also click the 'Bonus chest' button when you're creating the world to jump start your adventure. This chest provides you with: Wooden or stone pickaxes, Wooden or stone axes, Logs, Wooden planks, Sticks, Bread and Apples. Additionally, four torches will spawn around the chest.

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma Pah! Kids today with their bonus chests. When I started, we didn't even have a wiki, and we had to run through the night, to the silent laughter of the critters. And we had to live in t'coal-scuttle.

Comment: ^ This. The concept, of starting a minecraft world, with SOMETHING, defeats the purpose, of starting a minecraft world.

Comment: @deworde true and i totally agree with you. Still, im only naming options.

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xe1a1wHxTyo